# Удаление функций из объекта/массива

Tags: массивы, javascript

```
myFunction(
['string'],
[
    [[10, 13], ['str1', 'str2'], ['str1_1'], ['#EE0000','#8B0000']],
    [[15, 12], ['str1', 'str2'], ['str1_1'], ['#EE0000','#8B0000']]
],
[10, 25]
);

function myFunction(param1, param2, param3) {

for ( var i = 0; i < param2.length; i++ ) {
    var data = param2[i];

    console.log(data); // => [Array[2], [Array[2], [Array[1], [Array[2] и вот эта херотень, которую хз что приписывает: $pnmap$: function, $pnforEach$: function, $pnall$: function...]

console.log(param2.length); // => 4

// data[0] тоже содержит такие функции, по этому при переборе выдает:

for ( key in data[0] ) {

    console.log( data[0][key] ); // => 10, 13, и function $$JSCompiler_prototypeAlias...

    console.log( typeof( data[0][key] )); // => 2 number и 6 function

}
}

// и каждый следующий массив их содержит
};
```

Вот полный текст:

```
function $$JSCompiler_prototypeAlias$$$$pnmap$$($f$$32$$,$opt_obj$$31$$){return $goog$array$map$$.apply(null,$pn$aargs_$$(this,arguments))} 
function $$JSCompiler_prototypeAlias$$$$pnforEach$$($f$$34$$,$opt_obj$$33$$){$goog$array$forEach$$.apply(null,$pn$aargs_$$(this,arguments));return this} 
function $$JSCompiler_prototypeAlias$$$$pnall$$($f$$38$$,$opt_obj$$37$$){return $goog$array$every$$.apply(null,$pn$aargs_$$(this,arguments))} 
function $$JSCompiler_prototypeAlias$$$$pnequals$$($arr2$$12$$,$opt_equalsFn$$1$$){return $goog$array$equals$$.apply(null,$pn$aargs_$$(this,arguments))} 
function $$JSCompiler_prototypeAlias$$$$pnfindIndex$$($f$$41$$,$opt_obj$$46$$){return $goog$array$findIndex$$.apply(null,$pn$aargs_$$(this,arguments))} 
function $$JSCompiler_prototypeAlias$$$$pnindexOf$$($obj$$76$$,$opt_fromIndex$$10$$){return $goog$array$indexOf$$.apply(null,$pn$aargs_$$(this,arguments))}
```

Что то, и как от него избавиться?

Подключен jqery 1.11.0

И bootstrap 3.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какая-то библиотека (не jQuery) меняет прототип  Array, но вообще перебор массива принято по длине  перебирать или, используя [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (похоже на closure-compiler) есть еще hasOwnProperty, тоже поможет https://stackoverflow.com/a/1107698/815386

Comment: eicto,
Спасибо, во всем виноват PicNet Table Filter. Отключил, все работает нормально.